# different onload script with greasemonkey give different behaviour in youtube

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I have a simple script that create a span in the page with some info taken by flash player API.
I tried 3 ways:

1) If I put the script with no onload or with:
       ( function (){ ...code here... }) ();

This doesn't load all my code correctly, particularly the player info part:

```
var spanSound=document.createElement('span');
Fls_div.appendChild(spanSound);
spanSound.appendChild(document.createTextNode("  audioLev:")); // --OK--

var player = window.document.getElementById('movie_player');
var spanQual= document.createElement('span');
spanQual.appendChild(document.createTextNode("-->" + player.getPlaybackQuality() ));  // --NO--
```

But all youtube's comments are loaded.

2) I put all the code into:

```
window.onload = function(){  ...code here... }
```

This does load all my code correctly, BUT it doesn't load the youtube's comments...

3) finally I tried:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(e) { ...code here... }, false);
```

this loads all correct, code and comments.

Why these 3 different behaviours ( particularly the 2) )?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 - The code runs before anything else is loaded. When you try things like document.getElementById, the elements don't exist yet, so your code won't find it.

2 - You're replacing the window.onload function. Looks like the page already has a onload function (that takes care of loading the comments..?) and when you asign another function to it, the first one will be replace and won't run anymore.

3 - You're adding an event listener. You can have multiple event listeners in a page, when the event happens, all of the event listeners will execute (compared to window.onload, where you can have only one function execute).